# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Values' of undefined (line 37, file "Code") - Google Apps Scrit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I've created a google apps script allowing me to create some Google Docs templates from a google sheets.

Here is the code :

```js
function createDocument2 () {
  var headers,i,L,scriptProps,tactics;
  var endRowToRange,rangeForDate,sh,sheetTabName,ss,ssFileID,startRowToRange,templateId;
 
  ssFileID = 'Google Sheet File ID';
  templateId = 'Google Doc Template ID';
  sheetTabName = "Google Sheet Tab Name";
  
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssFileID);
  sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetTabName);
  endRowToRange = sh.getLastRow(); //The end row number will always be the last row in the sheet tab
  Logger.log(endRowToRange);
  
  scriptProps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  
  startRowToRange = scriptProps.getProperty('startRow'); // Where the start row begins for this run of the code  

  /* endRowToRange = endRowToRange.toString(); //Needs to be a string to concatenate the A1 notation */
  
  startRowToRange = startRowToRange.slice(0,startRowToRange.indexOf(".")); // Remove the decimal places FROM THE STRING
  /* endRowToRange = endRowToRange.slice(0,endRowToRange.indexOf(".")); // Remove the decimal places */
  Logger.log(endRowToRange);
  
  if (!startRowToRange) {
    startRowToRange = 2;
  }

  
  rangeForDate = 'A' + startRowToRange + ":I" + endRowToRange; // Build the A1 Notation for the data range


  Logger.log('rangeForDate' + rangeForDate);
  
  // Where we fill the Google Docs template

  
  headers = sh.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ssFileID,'A1:I1');
  tactics = sh.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ssFileID,rangeForDate);

  L = tactics.values.length;
  var i;
  
  for (i = 0; i < L; i ++) {

    Logger.log (tactics);

    var fpn = tactics.values[i][0];
    var nom = tactics.values[i][1];
    var cp = tactics.values[i][2];
    var tel = tactics.values[i][3];
    var email = tactics.values[i][4];
    var type = tactics.values[i][5];
    var prog = tactics.values[i][6];
    var date = tactics.values[i][7];
    var time = tactics.values[i][8];

    var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy().getId();
    DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName(fpn + ' ' + nom.toUpperCase());

    var head = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getHeader();
    head.replaceText ('##FP##', fpn);

    var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();
    body.replaceText ('##NOM##', nom);
    body.replaceText ('##CP##', cp);
    body.replaceText ('##EMAIL##', email);
    body.replaceText ('##TEL##', tel);
    body.replaceText ('##TYPE##', type);
    body.replaceText ('##PROG##', prog);
    body.replaceText ('##DATE##', date);
    body.replaceText ('##TIME##', time);

  }
  
  // Loop to retreive the values processed before
  
  scriptProps.setProperty('startRow',endRowToRange + 1); // Save new start value
}
```

I've duplicated this script to another folder and it's not working anymore, it's saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Values' of undefined (line 37, file "Code") - Google Apps Scrit".

When I run it from my initial folder, it's working perfectly.

Does anybody have an ideas about the problem ?

Thank you in advance.
Matt

Comment: Have your tried changing to `headers = sh.getRange('A1:I1').getValues();
tactics =sh.getRange(rangeForDate).getValues();`

Comment: Hi @Ghost, thank you for your answer. I tried but it's not working too. I do not have the error anymore but it's not creating my template. Should I change the values below also ?Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi @matthiew Its hard to look at this way. I really need to look at your spreadsheet and see why its not working. Maybe if you can post link to your sample sheet and describe what you want to achieve, I can help

Comment: Hi @Ghost, thank you for your answer. I'll try to explain you easily. I have a landing page that receive some leads. All the leads are stored into a google sheets automatically. I have 3 landing pages running, so on my google sheet file, I have 3 tabs eg: LP 1, LP 2, LP 3. Once the datas are stored in the google sheet, the script shared above is creating some prospect pages with the customer datas automatically. The script find the new datas added and then create the google doc prospect page.

Comment: @Ghost I have 3 folders eg : LP 1, LP 2, LP 3 all containing the google doc template and the script so the prospect pages can be stored and we can know from which landing page the prospect come. On the folder LP 1, when I run the script, it's working. On the LP 2 and LP 3 folder, the script is doing the error mentioned above.

Comment: @Ghost here is the link to see the google sheet : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pVc-REdwgORpwN36l5MD1U2V8DRDPySg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Ghost https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dFT81ZT3h1FE8HFPunlm17WYyWCoR2dk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Ghost https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uuZcrwIa3e5vcjawkuek1mPH8KxCli6W/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello.. just one more question. When you say you run on LP2 and LP3 folder its giving error. How are you specifying different folder ?

Comment: Hello @Ghost, thank you for your answer. I just place the duplicated script into the folder LP2 and LP3... Maybe the problem comes from this yes ? Should I mention to the script which folder ?

Comment: Hey Matthieu, My profile has my twitter link. Maybe you can DM me .. we can discuss the best approach and then I can comeback and write answer here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you need to make a few changes.

After

```
startRowToRange = scriptProps.getProperty('startRow');
```

add

```
if(endRowToRange<startRowToRange) return;
```

change headers and tactics to

```
headers = sh.getRange('A1:I1').getValues();
tactics = sh.getRange(rangeForDate).getValues();
```

instead of tactic.values use just tactics